# dojo ValidationTextBox duplicating string

Tags: spring, validation, dojo

I'm using the dojo toolkit in my spring-roo application. I have two dijit.form.ValidationTextBox that I use in a spring form. I want to be able to type in one textbox and modify that text and have it appear in another textbox. I have not had any success using dojo/on in my spring-roo app. Is there an alternative. Possibly combining a ValidationTextBox with jquery keypress event handler. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to see the change happen on every keystroke, set the textboxes' property "intermediateChanges" to true, then try this (assuming you set your TextBoxes declaratively, and set an id to each of them) :

```
require(["dijit/registry"], function(registry){
    var textBox1 = registry.byId("yourTextBox1Id"),
        textBox2 = registry.byId("yourTextBox2Id");

    textBox1.on("change", function(value){
        textBox2.set("value", value);
    });
});
```

See http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dijit/form/TextBox.html, example on the paragraph "Getting and Manipulating the Value".

See also http://jsfiddle.net/psoares/3b8UM/

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I've since solved this and I found out that spring-roo auto includes dojo but the version it includes is incomplete and doesn't include the "dojo/on" function. However, for what it's worth you're answer is correct. Thank you.

Comment: It looks like Spring roo still ships dojo 1.6.0. This post might help, if you need to upgrade : http://jpgmr.wordpress.com/2011/04/19/using-a-different-version-of-dojo-in-a-spring-roo-generated-project/

Comment: Hmmm not sure why my version wasn't up to date. Anyway thanks for this.

Comment: Oh I see Dojo is at 1.9 now. Ok I'll make sure I do that upgrade.